# Start lazarus FORM application from SSH Client

Tags: console, x11, lazarus

Does anybody know how to execute a lazarus application with forms from the SSH Client PUTTY on my WIN32 machine? So it piles up in the GUI while typing in my putty client.

Great Thanks, Wouter, PascalByThree

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czxgt.jpg)